# calculate the height of a resized node

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have created a longpress gesture to make the spot run the resize action,but i don't know how to calculate the height of spot after resizing. I want another sprite node of"feiji" move some distance which is exactly the height that the spot have resized. I have tried to get the speed of spot and the time it ran,so that i can calculate the height by multiplying them. But it didn't work, and the feiji didn't run action.

```
SKSpriteNode *spot;
NSDate *startTime;
NSTimeInterval pressTime;
SKSpriteNode *feiji = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"feiji.png"];
feiji.position =CGPointMake(100,120);
[self addChild:feiji];

UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longGus = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longGus:)];
longGus.minimumPressDuration=0.1;
[[self view]addGestureRecognizer:longGus];


-(void)longGus:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gesture
{
    
    if (UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan==gesture.state) {
        [self stickAction];
        startTime = [NSDate date];
    }
    
    if (UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged==gesture.state) {
        [self stickAction];
    }
    

   if (UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded==gesture.state) {
        [spot removeAllActions];

        pressTime  = -[startTime timeIntervalSinceNow];

        SKAction *down = [SKAction rotateByAngle:-M_PI/2 duration:0.5];
        [spot runAction:down completion:^{
            [self feijiMove];
        }];

  }
```

-(void)feijiMove
{
    SKAction *move = [SKAction moveByX:(10/self.size.width) * pressTime y:0 duration:2];
    [feiji runAction:move];
}

-(void)stickAction
{
    spot = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor blackColor] size:CGSizeMake(5, 5)];
    spot.position = CGPointMake(100, 100);
    spot.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);

SKAction *resize = [SKAction resizeByWidth:0 height:self.size.width duration:10];
[spot runAction:resize];
[self addChild:spot];
}

Comment: i don't exactly understand what you are trying to achieve. do you need to add a new spot overtime a long press is done and changes?

Comment: @rakeshbs sorry, i posted part of code. i created a sprite node*feiji, i want the feiji to run a move-action for some distance after long press is done. now my question is how to calculate the distance.i will edit again to post all codes.